# Pandas : Merge in loop does not work, but works on each table separately?

Tags: loops, pandas, merge

I had to slice the table I'm working on in pieces, because it was to heavy for Pandas and I'm using a loop to apply my treatments on each piece, using a dictionnary. It's been working fine, until I had to apply a merge on each piece, using the same DataFrame for the left :

```
for piece, df in d.iteritems():
   df = pd.merge(df,table_left, on='column', how='inner')
```

It doesn't raise any error, but the columns of my left table are not added. 
Weird thing is, when I use the same code on one of my tables, out of the loop, it works fine... 
Any idea of what I'm missing there anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are only changing the iterated value in your `for` loop as `df` is a local object in loop. By re-assigning that iterated value, the merge only remains in that state during the current iteration. You do not re-assign the value's source, namely the dictionary, `d`.

Consider updating the dictionary element inside `for` loop by explicitly referring the dictionary:

```
for piece, df in d.iteritems():
   d[piece] = pd.merge(df, table_left, on='column', how='inner')
```

Alternatively, try a dictionary comprehension:

```
new_dict = {piece: pd.merge(df, table_left, on='column', how='inner') for piece, df in d.iteritems()}
```